# How to make out of an HTML text a DOM object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have an app where a page generator creates a start page that is saved in the database. The saved information is just the `outerHTML` of the DOM object. To create the edit function, I need an inverse function that recreates the DOM object out of the HTML information. Unfortunately, assigning the decrypted information to the `outerHTML` section results in nothing, as the changes in the DOM object are ignored.

**My question:** How can I recreate a DOM object out of saved outerHTML information? If this is impossible, what would be the right way to do such a thing?

**EDIT**
Thank you for your reply! Here are some snippets of code that show what I am doing. The prototype *MainWidget* is getting information from the HTML page & wants to assign the information. Used functions are part of another object (prototype) called *Widgets*.

```
var asserts = new Asserts();
var calls = new Calls();
var constants = new MainConst();
var strings = new Strings();
var widgets = new MainWidget();

MainWidget.method('assign2Widget', function (call, label, value, isValid) {
    isValid = toBoolean(isValid), value = strings.toString(value);

    if (calls.isValid(call) && strings.hasMinimalLength(label, 2)) {
        var section = (!label.includes('Builder')  // A marker, not an element!
                        && !label.includes(constants.NewsTicker))
            ? widgets.getSgSectionByLabel(document, label)
            : null;
        value = strings.decode(decodeURIComponent(value));      //<<<< Code decoded from DB

        if (asserts.isObject(section)) {
            section.outerHTML = value;
        } else if (label.includes(constants.Elements)) {
            if (asserts.isValid(infos.Elements) && infos.Elements.length > 0) {
                // HERE, THE CODE FROM DB SHOULD BE ADDED TO WIDGET.
                // The "label" gives the label of the widget, and the "value" is
                // what is to be assigned to.
            }
        } else if (label.includes(constants.NewsTicker)) {
            […]
        }
        […]
});

Widget.method('getElementTypeByLabel', function (thing, elementType, label) {
    if (asserts.isObject(thing)
        && strings.hasMinimalLength(elementType, 2)
        && strings.hasMinimalLength(label, 2)) {

        var element, elements = document.getElementsByTagName(elementType);

        if (asserts.isValid(elements)
            && asserts.isDefined(elements.length) && elements.length === 0) {

            elements = thing.children;
        }
        for (var i = 0; asserts.isDefined(elements.length) && i < elements.length; i++) {
            element = elements*;

            if (element.getAttribute !== null) {
                var labelName = element.getAttribute(constants.label);

                if (label === labelName && element !== null) {
                    return element;
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        // If the element was not found, search recursively the elements!
        for (var i = 0; asserts.isDefined(elements.length) && i < elements.length; i++) {
            return this.getElementTypeByLabel(elements*, elementType, label);
        }
    } else {
        // Error! //messages.invalidFunctionCall(functionName);
    }
    return null;
});

Widget.method('getSgSectionByLabel', function (element, label) {
    return this.getElementTypeByLabel(element, 'sg-section', label);
});
```

**EDIT 2**: I used only the changes done in the `sg-section` to recreate the contents when editing an existing page.

```
MainWidget.js:
[…]
MainWidget.method('assign2Widget', function (call, label, value, isValid) {
    isValid = toBoolean(isValid), value = strings.toString(value);

    if (calls.isValid(call) && strings.hasMinimalLength(label, 2)) {
        var section = (!label.includes('Builder')  // A marker, not an element!
                        && !label.includes(constants.NewsTicker))
            ? widgets.getSgSectionByLabel(document, label)
            : null;
        value = strings.decode(decodeURIComponent(value));

        if (asserts.isObject(section)) {
            section.outerHTML = value;
        } else if (label.includes(constants.Elements)) {
            if (asserts.isString(value) && value.includes(LeftBracket)) {
                value = arrays.toArray(value);  //value.replace(LeftBracket, '').split(RightBracket);
            }
            if (arrays.isArray(value)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    infos.insertGridItem(value[i]);
                }
            }
            […]

MainInfos.js:
[…]
function MainInfos() {
    this.Elements;                      // Object for startGridGenerator
    this.insertGridItem;                // Function of startGridGenerator
    this.PrototypeName = 'MainInfos';
}

MainInfos.inherits(Infos);

MainWidget.method('assign2Widget', function (call, label, value, isValid) {
    isValid = toBoolean(isValid), value = strings.toString(value);

    if (calls.isValid(call) && strings.hasMinimalLength(label, 2)) {
        var section = (!label.includes('Builder')  // A marker, not an element!
                        && !label.includes(constants.NewsTicker))
            ? widgets.getSgSectionByLabel(document, label)
            : null;
        value = strings.decode(decodeURIComponent(value));

        if (asserts.isObject(section)) {
            section.outerHTML = value;
        } else if (label.includes(constants.Elements)) {
            if (asserts.isString(value) && value.includes(LeftBracket)) {
                value = arrays.toArray(value);  //value.replace(LeftBracket, '').split(RightBracket);
            }
            if (arrays.isArray(value)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    infos.insertGridItem(value[i]);
                }
            }
        } else if (label.includes(constants.NewsTicker)) {
            […]
        }
});

startGridGenerator.js:
[…]
(function () {
    var moduleName = 'ivmGridBuilder';

    var controllerName = moduleName + Controller;

    angular.module(moduleName, [
        'ionic',
        'ui.sortable',
        'ivmColorpicker',
        'ivmIconpicker'
    ])
        .controller(controllerName, function ($scope,
                                              $ionicScrollDelegate,
                                              $ionicModal,
                                              $sce,
                                              CommunicationService) {
            […]
            /**
             * Inserts an existing grid item to the item's array
             *
             * @param item
             */
            $scope.insertGridItem = function (item) {
                if (asserts.isObject(item)) {
                    $scope.items.push(item);
                    infos.Elements.push(item);
                    $ionicScrollDelegate.resize()
                } else {
                    // First call with no valid item & "remember" this function
                    // by having a link to in in object MainInfos!
                    infos.insertGridItem = $scope.insertGridItem;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should be like, you get the a HTML string with the contents. Then you use the `$sce.trustAsHtml();` and assign to a scope variable which will ensure the HTML is safe then you can use the HTML below which has the directive `ng-bind-html` to render the HTML String as actual HTML.

Here is a working example of the same.

```js
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);
app.controller("appController", function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.content = "This text is <em>html capable</em> meaning you can have <a href=\"#\">all</a> sorts <b>of</b> html in here.";
  $scope.output = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>Rendering HTML with angularJS</h2>
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <div ng-bind-html="output"></div>
</div>
```

Another option is to use `ng-sanitize`.

If you use `ng-sanitize` - Inputs are sanitized by parsing the HTML into tokens. All safe tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped html string. This means that no unsafe input can make it into the returned string.

Refer the below question for a more detailed explanation.

<kbd>**SO Answer**</kbd>

---

```js
var app = angular.module("angularApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("appController", function($scope) {
  $scope.content = "This text is <em>html capable</em> meaning you can have <a href=\"#\">all</a> sorts <b>of</b> html in here.";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<h2>Rendering HTML with angularJS</h2>
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <div ng-bind-html="content"></div>
</div>
```

As seen in the above example there is no need for calling `$sce.trustAsHtml();` since `ngSanitize` will take care of it automatically.

Let me know if this approach help you, or if you face any issues with the same!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOMParser()` to create a `#document`, or `<template>` element to create a `#document-fragment` from a string

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(/* outerHTML */, "text/html");
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try whether I can use this to replace the empty `sg-section` object in the DOM with the saved `sg-section` `outerHTML` information.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the string into a hidden Div in page, then get with javascript the elements you want from that Div. Like in this code:

```
var str ='abc 123<div id="test">coursesweb.net</div><span class="cls">some text</span>';
document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div style="display:none;">'+str+'</div>');
var ob_test = document.getElementById('test');
alert(ob_test.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have so-called `sg-section` object that is created by the page generator, which I save in the database. Is it possible to change the existing empty object with the one in the database using the trick of a hidden element?

Comment: Try this: `document.querySelector('#sg-section_id').outerHTML ='html string';` . Or, if sg-section is an object in JS: `sg-section.outerHTML ='html string';`

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I thought whether it is better to save a whole `sg-section` or just the changed content & could use the latter so that I saved the JavaScript object only.